# How to use separate Windows batch file with using FOR (tokens, delims)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, token

I would like to make a performance monitoring batch program. I myself made insert VB. But the thing is, I can't make a file which is for insert

1. dump performance monitoring file
2. process the file into insert-able data
3. send to a server via FTP
4. insert the data

Except 2nd I made it all

would anybody help how to separate the data to what I want to make?

The dump file is like this

```
------------------------------------------------
**# 20180917_CAFENOIR_PERF.cvs**
------------------------------------------------
"(PDH-CSV 4.0) (","\\CAFENOIR\Processor(_Total)\% Processor time","\\CAFENOIR\Memory\Available KBytes","\\CAFENOIR\LogicalDisk(C:)\% Free Space","\\CAFENOIR\LogicalDisk(D:)\% Free Space","\\CAFENOIR\LogicalDisk(E:)\% Free Space"
"09/17/2018 12:32:11.439"," ","2389340","73.031078258802481","99.758165860552879","92.077869960114995"
"09/17/2018 12:32:12.474","13.17071949707611","2393976","73.031078258802481","99.758165860552879","92.077869960114995"
```

and I want to make the file like this

```
------------------------------------------------
**# 20180917_12_CAFENOIR_perfmon.imp**
------------------------------------------------
CAFENOIR
"13.17071949707611"
"2393976"
"73.031078258802481"
"99.758165860552879"
"92.077869960114995"
"09/17/2018 12:32:12.474"
```

I tried with a script like this but it just outputs the computername

```
CAFENOIR
```

I hope anyone gives a clue

**added Code (Sorry I forgot)**

```
for /F "tokens=1-6 skip=2 delims=," %%a IN ('type *.cvs') do (@echo %computername% %%b% %%c% %%d% %%e% %%f% %%a% > %date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%%time:~0,2%%computername%_perfmon.imp
```

)

Comment: Please revisit your question and answer, select the file content and code sections separately and press the `{}` button to format it and make it readable.

Comment: It's unclear what you're saying by "I myself made insert VB. But the thing is, I can't make a file which is for insert". And what's "insert-able data"? Why insert the data after it has been sent to the server?

Comment: the reason why i wanna make those file is to insert data into DB for monitoring.
so i made insert batch but i couldn't make dump file..

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your answer, there are way to many issues with it. You could have run a single loop, and there is no such thing as `%%a%`:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1-6 skip=2 delims=," %%a IN ('type *.cvs') do (
    set "vDT=%%a"
    set "vCPU=%%b"
    set "vMEM=%%c" 
    set "vCfree=%%d"
    set "vDfree=%%e"
    set "vEfree=%%f"
echo %computername% %vCPU% %vMEM% %vCfree% %vDfree% %vEfree% %vDT% > %date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%%time:~0,2%%computername%_perfmon.imp
)
```

Even better, you do not need to even set the variables as you predefine them already:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1-6 skip=2 delims=," %%a IN ('type *.cvs') do (
echo %computername% %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%a > %date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%%time:~0,2%%computername%_perfmon.imp
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your helping.
**%%a%** is happened while i was edit the script.
i was confused.
i looked the help by "?" and blogs and .. simply it was miss understood of syntax.

again thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

It's funny. I was struggling for a week for this, but after I posted the question I just did it myself

I hope it's gonna help someone who what separate A file parameters.

```
@SET vCPU   = none
@SET vMEM   = none
@SET vCfree = none
@SET vDfree = none
@SET vEfree = none
@SET vDT    = none
FOR /F "tokens=1 skip=2 delims=," %%a IN ('type *.cvs') DO @SET vDT=%%a%
FOR /F "tokens=2 skip=2 delims=," %%a IN ('type *.cvs') DO @SET vCPU=%%a%
FOR /F "tokens=3 skip=2 delims=," %%a IN ('type *.cvs') DO @SET vMEM=%%a%
FOR /F "tokens=4 skip=2 delims=," %%a IN ('type *.cvs') DO @SET vCfree=%%a%
FOR /F "tokens=5 skip=2 delims=," %%a IN ('type *.cvs') DO @SET vDfree=%%a%
FOR /F "tokens=6 skip=2 delims=," %%a IN ('type *.cvs') DO @SET vEfree=%%a%
@echo %vCPU%
@echo %vMEM%
@echo %vCfree%
@echo %vDfree%
@echo %vEfree%
@echo %vDT%
@echo %computername% %vCPU% %vMEM% %vCfree% %vDfree% %vEfree% %vDT% > %date:~0,4%%date:~5,2%%date:~8,2%_%time:~0,2%_%computername%_perfmon.imp**
```

Comment: please learn how to format texts properly by pressing the `?` in the editing box while posting or by clicking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). And commands like `vCPU   = none` or `vMEM   = none` won't work because spaces in `set` are significant. Besides [`%date%` is not a good way to get date](https://superuser.com/q/1287756/241386)

Comment: 1. I didn't realize that when set a parameter, where wouldn't be space. (Thanks)
2. Thank you for the link, i think, i should change the way to name files.